# Having problems using arrays and a while loop

Tags: arduino

I am trying to design a simple 4 button program to create a passcode using arrays and a while loop, but when ever I run the while loop it crashes the arduino I'm using. Here is the code I am using.

```
bool code() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (input[i] != password[i]){
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }
}

void loop() {
    int RButtonstate = digitalRead(RButton);
    int GButtonstate = digitalRead(GButton);
    int BButtonstate = digitalRead(BButton);
    int YButtonstate = digitalRead(YButton);
    int z = 0;
    while (z <= size){
        if (RButtonstate = LOW){
            input[z] = 0;
            z++;
        }
        if (GButtonstate = LOW){
            input[z] = 1;
            z++;
        }
        if (BButtonstate = LOW){
            input[z] = 2;
            z++;
        }
        if (YButtonstate = LOW){
            input[z] = 3;
            z++;
        }
    }
    bool test = code();
    if (test == true) {
        tone(Buzzer, 100, 100);
        delay(100);
        tone(Buzzer, 200, 100);
        delay(100);
        tone(Buzzer, 300, 100);
        delay(100);
        tone(Buzzer, 400, 100);
        delay(100);
    }else{
        tone(Buzzer, 100, 1000);
        delay(500);
        delay(100000000);
    }
    delay(1000000);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's related but I think you want `=` and not `==` in your if conditions,

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you check `z` at the beginning but then possibly increment `z` multiple times. For instance if the value of `z` is `size - 1` and more than one of the button states is LOW you will start writing beyond the array (let's assume that you fixed the bugs around using `=` instead of `==` for comparison). I also don't know how the input array is defined but array indexes are 0 based. Your condition in the while loop is likely not correct. The loop will be entered when `z` is equal to `size` but since array indexes are zero based the last index is `size - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your full code, but this line

`while (z <= size) {`

should probably be:

`while (z < size) {`

And as @Pawel said, you probably want to change this:

`if (RButtonstate = LOW) {`

to this:

`if (RButtonstate == LOW) {`